# Animate android activity change

Tags: android, animation, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm trying to animate an activity transition. Basically what I want to do is the following:

1.) Perform a circular clip of a specific view

2.) Begin a fade transition

3.) perform a circular reveal on the new activity of a specific view.

My knee jerk reaction was to use the

```
ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(getActivity(), R.transition.myanim, 0)
```

method and pass that bundle into my start activity intent. However, I can't seem to get any animation to *actually* work. The animation I'm trying out is the following transition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transitionSet  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:transitionOrdering="sequential">
<transition class="com.my.app.transition.RevealTransition" android:transitionVisibilityMode="mode_out"/>
<fade/>
<targets>
    <target android:targetId="@id/startButton"/>
</targets>
```

Instead I just get no animation. Just a switch to the new activity. The documentation seems...limited so I'm hoping someone here can help me out. Thanks.

Note: I stole the  RevealTransition class from a google blog post - I don't think that's the problem because the fade doesn't fire either.

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually set the transition to be used?

upon finish or startActivity you must call the Activity's overridePendingTransition to explicitly set the transitions

```
public void overridePendingTransition(int enterAnim, int exitAnim)
```

f.ex if you have the animations 'enter_from_right' and 'exit_to_left' defined, and you wish to exit the current Activity with these animations:

```
finish();
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_left);
```

Comment: What's the point of the makeSceneTransitionAnimation call then? It seems like if you have to also call overridePendingTransition the previously mentioned call isn't doing anything.

Sorry - I didn't specify in the post, but the makeSceneTransitionAnimation option/bundle takes the exit and enter animations.

Comment: I'm a bit unfamiliar with makeSceneTransitionAnimation, but it seems it is API Level 21. You can call `toBundle()` on the `ActivityOptions` object returned by `ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation` and use that bundle as an options bundle as argument for ` startActivity (Intent intent, Bundle options)`. Of course you do not call overridePendingTransition if you do it like this.

Comment: I should've been clearer in the OP (will edit now) but that is what I'm doing.